# Trying to get the Active cores,confused with the usage of GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx Winapi

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

```
LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_RELATIONSHIP Relationship = {};
SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX *m_pinfoBase = nullptr;
SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX *m_pinfoCurrent = nullptr;
DWORD m_cbRemaining = 0;
DWORD cb = 0;

m_pinfoBase =reinterpret_cast<SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX *>(LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, cb));

if (!GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx(Relationship,
    m_pinfoBase, &cb))
{
    printf("Error 1 %d\n",GetLastError());
    //return;
}
else
{
    printf("ActiveCores:%d\n", m_pinfoBase->Group.GroupInfo->ActiveProcessorCount);
}
```

I looked up the documentation in, [usage details of the api](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131028-00/?p=2823), also I looked up SO and other links and I wrote a small snippet to fetch the Active cores and the api GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx is returning ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER. I have two questions,

1. The proper ActiveProcessorCount in the _PROCESSOR_GROUP_INFO structures gives the count of Active i.e unparked cores?
2. What's wrong in my code snippe

Comment: Why did you allocate 0 bytes? There are plenty of examples on the web showing how to do this. Why would you use LocalAlloc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ActiveProcessorCount: The number of active processors in the **group**.

---

> 2.What's wrong in my code snippet ?

absolute all

code example how work with [`GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405488(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
void TestLP2()
{
    ULONG rcb = 0x100, Size, err;

    PVOID buf;

    BOOL fOk;

    do 
    {
        if (buf = new UCHAR[rcb])
        {
            fOk = GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx(RelationAll, (PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX)buf, &rcb);

            err = GetLastError();

            if (fOk)
            {
                if (rcb)
                {
                    union {
                        PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX pslpi;
                        PBYTE pb;
                    };

                    pslpi = (PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX)buf;

                    do 
                    {
                        DumpLPI(pslpi);

                        Size = pslpi->Size;
                        pb += Size;

                    } while (rcb -= Size);
                }
            }

            delete [] buf;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    } while (!fOk && err == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
}
```

the implementation of `DumpLPI` can be next:

```
void DumpLPI(PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX pslpi)
{
    union {
        PPROCESSOR_RELATIONSHIP Processor;
        PNUMA_NODE_RELATIONSHIP NumaNode;
        PCACHE_RELATIONSHIP Cache;
        PGROUP_RELATIONSHIP Group;
    };

    Processor = &pslpi->Processor;

    switch (pslpi->Relationship)
    {
    case RelationProcessorPackage:
        DbgPrint("RelationProcessorPackage(GroupCount = %u)\n", Processor->GroupCount);

        if (WORD GroupCount = Processor->GroupCount)
        {
            PGROUP_AFFINITY GroupMask = Processor->GroupMask;
            do 
            {
                DbgPrint("group<%u> Mask = %08x\n", GroupMask->Group, GroupMask->Mask);
            } while (GroupMask++, --GroupCount);
        }
        break;

    case RelationProcessorCore:
        DbgPrint("RelationProcessorCore(%x): Mask = %08x\n", Processor->Flags, Processor->GroupMask->Mask);
        break;

    case RelationGroup:
        DbgPrint("RelationGroup(%u/%u)\n", Group->ActiveGroupCount, Group->MaximumGroupCount);

        if (WORD ActiveGroupCount = Group->ActiveGroupCount)
        {
            PPROCESSOR_GROUP_INFO GroupInfo = Group->GroupInfo;
            do 
            {
                DbgPrint("<%u/%u %08x>",
                    GroupInfo->ActiveProcessorCount, 
                    GroupInfo->MaximumProcessorCount, 
                    GroupInfo->ActiveProcessorMask);
            } while (GroupInfo++, --ActiveGroupCount);
        }
        break;

    case RelationCache:
        DbgPrint("Cache L%u (%x, %x) %x\n", Cache->Level, Cache->LineSize, Cache->CacheSize, Cache->Type);
        break;

    case RelationNumaNode:
        DbgPrint("NumaNode<%u> (group = %u, mask = %08x)\n", NumaNode->NodeNumber, NumaNode->GroupMask.Group, NumaNode->GroupMask.Mask);
        break;
    default:
        DbgPrint("unknown Relationship=%x\n", pslpi->Relationship);
    }
}
```

example of output:

```
RelationProcessorPackage(GroupCount = 1)
group<0> Mask = 0000000f
RelationProcessorCore(1): Mask = 00000003
Cache L1 (40, 8000) 2
Cache L1 (40, 8000) 1
Cache L2 (40, 40000) 0
Cache L3 (40, 300000) 0
RelationProcessorCore(1): Mask = 0000000c
Cache L1 (40, 8000) 2
Cache L1 (40, 8000) 1
Cache L2 (40, 40000) 0
NumaNode<0> (group = 0, mask = 0000000f)
RelationGroup(1/1)
<4/4 0000000f>
```

Comment: alloca? Really? This is a total novice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `alloca` (same as `_alloca`) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx. why not ? I work with this kind of code (for unknown buffer size many years). and this is absolute correct. I can use it because deep understand how variables allocated in stack, how stack allocation work. but however I understand that "This is a total novice" as you say - for this I and paste alternative implementation - `TestLP2()`. however if  `TestLP()` - hurt someone's feelings I can delete it - no problem

Comment: Simplicity is best for beginners. Don't offer too many choices. Don't use LocalAlloc also, use new for c++

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - ok - I remove variant with `_alloca` (let this kind of code will be only for me :) ) and use `new/delete` however `LocalAlloc` used in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131028-00/?p=2823 - this answer why OP "Why would you use LocalAlloc?" - he copy-paste code.

Comment: `delete buf` needs to be `delete[] buf` instead.  In any case, the Win32 API is designed with a C-style interface, and thus can be used by any programming language that is compatible with C. `new`/`delete` are specific to C++ only. That is why Win32 API examples tend to use `LocalAlloc()` and other C-style memory allocation functions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `delete buf' not a error here and worked. what here I use for memory allocate/free - at all absolute not related. what is different what I use for allocation ?!? very strange comment

Comment: @RbMm: just because it does not fail at compile-time does not mean it is not an error. `delete buf` is a code bug on your part, and one that cannot be detected by the compiler.  Memory allocated with `new` **must** be freed with `delete`, and memory allocated with `new[]` **must** be freed with `delete[]`.  If you mismatch them, you can cause runtime errors, crashes, memory leaks, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - i do not notice such things because always use overload new/delete operators and `operator new[](size_t)` have the same code as `operator new(size_t)` in my code, but even in standard crt implementation (`delete_array.cpp` ) i view that `void __CRTDECL operator delete[](void* block) noexcept
{
    operator delete(block);
}` but in any case you right here - even if implementation is equal need call `delete []` for `new []` - my mistake. but this anyway not related to Win32 API - no different how i allocate memory storage for API

Comment: @RbMm how the memory is **used** is different than how the memory is **allocated**. The Win32 API does not care how you allocate memory buffers you supply to it (it does care when it allocates buffers for you, though).

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, but exactly this I and try say at begin. "The Win32 API does not care how you allocate memory, when you supply your own buffers to it " may be my bad English here

Comment: @RemyLebeau - about [] . when we use `new CSomeObject[n]` - `CSomeObject` can have overloaded operators new/delete and effect of `delete` and `delete[]` can be different. but for scalar type `UCHAR` both operators (with and without []) have the same effect. but even if same effect - again - you absolute right here and my mistake in initial code

Comment: @RbMm: in the case of `new CSomeObject[n]`, regardless of how memory is allocated, you must use `delete[]` to ensure that `~CSomeObject()` gets called on *every* array element. Using `delete` instead will not do that. Regardless of memory management, it is *undefined behavior* to call `delete` on `new[]`'d memory, and `delete[]` on `new`'d memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, you are right. and I already 3-rd time wrote about this. however I use delete on type `UCHAR` where `delete` and `delete[]` is the same and `UCHAR` have not destructor

Comment: @RbMm Why not just follow the rules?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - you mean `if (p=new char[n]) { delete p; }` ? yes, i admit it's **my fault**. i ofcourse understand that allocation and deallocation of memory should match each other. only thing i can say in my defense - in the case of a scalar type `UCHAR` effect of `delete` and `delete []` is equal. (only if `operator delete[](void*)` not special overloaded). of course in case object with constructor/destructor this is already real bug. excuse me

Comment: It is only equal if you rely on implementation detail. I know that's how you like to work, but it's not a great example to set, in my view.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - yes, not great. but in my case - i not use `CRT` at all. never. so i need implement global operators new/delete yourself. in my implementation this is equal. and in general i not rely on  implementation detail. i always try understand what is under the hood. this is very help write effective code and give freedom make not standard things (like in my first variant with cumulative `_alloca` call in loop). but this is not equal to rely on volatile implementation. but all this already offtop here. in concrete case need use `delete[] buf` and my fault

Comment: You contradict yourself. "I don't rely on implementation detail". "I try to understand what is under the hood". Those statements contradict each other.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - not agree here. understanding not equal rely on concrete implementation. in all case understanding very helpful. even if i do not use it direct or indirect. in some case (really rarely) i can decide - what is volatile details of implementation on which of course never can rely, and what is fundamental (that most likely will never change) and take a chance to use it (if no another way). but again "understanding" != "rely". this is like `WRK` source for kernel developers. very helpful, even if not direct rely on something

Comment: So, can you explain why the c++ standard exists then?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry not understand your last sentence. if you mean `delete` vs `delete[]` - i full I fully admit my mistake

Comment: The C++ standard exists so that developers can write code that will work as intended when compiled with any standard compliant compiler. If you rely on specifics of one compiler/runtime then you cannot predict what will happen when that code is handed to another compiler.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - exist many compiler specific feature. i always use only `CL` and it "Microsoft" extension syntax, which of course not valid for say `gcc`. about runtime implementation - this is already another. I do not argue about this and fully admit my mistake. I just tried to explain why it is in my code (for me only) does not lead to a memory leak and why I did not notice it

Comment: It's fine. I'm just trying to give you a perspective from other programmers' lives.